# drop down box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two drop down boxes.One drop box has values as may the other as 1.Now i change the first drop down value to june but will not change second drop box value.Here it is not passing second drop box because i have initiated using click event.Here i use live(click)but do i do that w/o clicking 2nd drop box that value should also pass

```
 **Updated**

 $(firstselect).live(click,function)
 $(secondselect).live(click,function)
```

Comment: Please post your code and ask a specific question. It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @DAFFODIL: That is not even valid JavaScript.... we cannot do anything with it.

Comment: @Felix Kling.Leave that one.You tell me how do i do my requirement.

Comment: @DAFFODIL: I don't even understand your requirement. That's why I said you have to clarify your question. It is not at all clear what you want.

Comment: @Felix Kling:Very simple.there are two select box.you select value from first and second value ,you do not select.You want it the previous selected one.How to send this two values.

Comment: @DAFFODIL: So the second select box should show the value that was previously selected in the first one?

Comment: I see. You should update your question and state this more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understood the problem:

> The second select box should show the value that was previously selected in the first one.

You could do like so:

```
var prevValue = $('#firstselect').val();

$('#firstselect').change(function() {
   $('#secondselect').val(prevValue);
   prevValue = this.value;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/wPh46/)

Bidirectional:

```
var prevValue = {
    'firstselect':  $('#firstselect').val(),
    'secondselect':  $('#secondselect').val()
};

$('select').change(function() {
    var other = this.id === 'firstselect' ? 'secondselect' : 'firstselect';

    prevValue[other] = $('#' + other).val();
    $('#' + other).val(prevValue[this.id]);
    prevValue[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/wPh46/1/)

Comment: @Felix Kling:Can you do this in jsfiddle.com

Comment: @DAFFODIL: Did it... but it is not more than I already posted.

Comment: @Felix Kling.I am confused,If you do it in jsfiddle.i can see the working and demo

Comment: @Fexlix Kling.alert the value.You ii find only one value getting alerted.

Comment: @Felix Kling:It should be bidirectional.Say i select second drop box and first box value should be prev selected one.

Comment: @DAFFODIL: Should not be that difficult to extend it. See my update.

Comment: @Felix Kling still the same.Alert and see the o/p.I need to pass this to $ajax to another page.

Comment: @Felix Kling:when you alert ,you should get two values.This is not happening.

Comment: @DAFFODIL: Where should I do an `alert`? Please change the fiddle accordingly and put comments to describe what the expected output should be. Thank you.

Comment: @Felix Kling: alert(prevValue[this.id]); I appreciate your help. 
o/p should be a&b

Comment: @DAFFODIL: `prevValue[this.id]` only holds the value of one element. If you want to get the values of both selects you have to concatenate it. You should also do something on your own ;) This site is for *helping*, not for *doing your work*.

Comment: @Felix Kling:I am not getting the o/p.that is reason i am asking here.

Comment: @DAFFODIL: But you don't state clearly *which* output you want, and *when* you want it. I hope you know how to get the current values of input element and how to do string concatenation. If not, then you should learn this first.

Comment: @Felix Kling:Now you under stood my question so correct the jsfiddle.

Comment: @DAFFODIL: No, I don't understand what you want now. The fiddle is correct you just have to integrate it in your code. I *helped* you, but I'm not doing your work. If you cannot go on from here alone, you have to read some jQuery tutorials first. How do you expect to use a tool if you don't know about it? Good luck!

Comment: @DAFFODIL: Tip for the future: Be nice to people who help you and don't expect/demand that they do everything for you. So far I have not seen that you tried anything on your own to solve the problem. That is the wrong attitude and it won't bring you far.